# Remove motion blur from fast moving objects

Tags: python, image-processing, motion-blur, kornia

I'm trying to implement a motion deblurring algorithm for fast moving objects (license plates) in a video.
What are the state of the art algorithms for doing that?

I saw extensive researches on single frame deblurring, and video deblurring for the whole video... but very few focused on fast moving objects (the last pubblication fund is this one: https://www.mecs-press.org/ijmecs//ijmecs-v2-n1/IJMECS-V2-N1-3.pdf, from 2010)

Do you have suggestions?

Comment: As a general rule, deblurring of fast moving objects does not work nicely.

Comment: your question constitutes research/opinions. such questions are considered "off-topic" for stack overflow. literature review is your responsibility. perhaps try the stack exchanges for AI/ML or DSP. the people there will expect you to put effort into the question as well (i.e. do your literature review).

Comment: deconvolving anything is a hassle, even more so if you don't have a Point Spread Function for the entire picture (but it varies by location, due to rotation, or just perspective projection)